The `pathToDriver` argument hasn't been specified
I was trying to connect the database using an R package, DatabaseConnector.
following is my code.
connDetails <- createConnectionDetails(dbms = 'postgresql', server = 'localhost/ohdsi', user = 'xxx', password = 'xxxx')

and then I got this error
Error in `checkPathToDriver()`:
! The `pathToDriver` argument hasn't been specified. Please set the path to the location containing the JDBC driver. See `?jdbcDrivers` for instructions on downloading the drivers.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

what should I do to solve the error?
I tried to specify the pathToDriver like this
pathToDriver <- '/Users/wnejd/Downloads'

then retried the code above, but got the same error

I don't know this specific package.   pathToDriver seems to be an argument of createConnectionDetails .
See: https://ohdsi.github.io/DatabaseConnector/articles/Connecting.html
